# Why does this html form not perform when the button is pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, function

I link my javascript to the html code but when the button is pressed, there are no alerts/popups. I do not understand how the button does not work. Where am I wrong within my code?

```
<form method="post" onSubmit="return formcontact();">

                <table align="center" cellpadding="5" width="500">
                <tr>
                <td><b>Name:</b></td>
                <td><input name="name" id="name" type="text" maxlength="50" placeholder="Full Name" style="width:350px; border:1px solid black;" class="ui-corner-all" ></td>
                </tr><tr>
                <td><b>Phone number:</b></td>
                <td><input name="phonenumber" id="phonenumber" type="text" maxlength="23" placeholder="Phone Number" style="width:350px; border:1px solid black;" class="ui-corner-all" ></td>
                </tr><tr>
                <td><b>Email address:</b></td>
                <td><input name="email" id="email" type="text" maxlength="50" placeholder="Email Address" style="width:350px; border:1px solid black;" class="ui-corner-all" ></td>
                </tr><tr>
                <td><b>Comments and questions:</b></td>
                <td><textarea name="comments" id="comments" rows="7" cols="35" style="width:350px; border:1px solid black;" class="ui-corner-all"></textarea></td>
                </tr><tr>
                </table> <br />


                <button type="button" class="contact1" onclick="formcontact()">Submit</button>
                <p id="submit"> </p>
                </form>

function formcontact(){
    var x = getElementById("name").value
    var u = getElementById("phonenumber").value
    var m = getElementById("email").value 
    var stay = getElementById("comments").value 
    var middle = m.indexOf("@");
    var end = m.lastIndexOf(".");

    if (x == ""){
        alert("Please fill out name. It is required.");
        return false
    }
    if (u == ""){
        alert("Please fill out phone number. It is required.");
        return false 
    }
    if (m == ""){
        alert("Please fill out email. It is required.");
        return false 
    }
    if (middle < 1 || middle < end +2 || end +2>=x.length) {
        alert("Sorry, but this is not a valid e-mail address");
        return false;
    }
    if (stay == ""){
        alert("Please enter the comments or questions field.")
    }
    var enter = "Thank You. Your message has been submitted";
    document.getElementById("submit").innerHTML = enter;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u0rbjvqL/

Comment: If you use jQuery at all, use it (none present but you tagged it jQuery). Your code will shrink by 60%+.Also, do not use `click` events on submit buttons. Keyboard form submission will bypass it.

Comment: You have multiple errors in your JSFiddle. "formcontact is not defined". JSFiddle has a problem accessing functions so change it to be `formcontact = function(){` (making it global scope). basically use your F12 console to view your errors and sort them out one by one :)

Answer (score 0):

Several problems:

- "formcontact is not defined". JSFiddle has a problem accessing functions so change it to be `formcontact = function(){` (making it global scope)
- It's `document.getElementById()' not just`getElementById()`

Basically use your F12 console to view your errors and sort them out one by one :)